# Dibujar poligonos y polilineas usando la api de google maps

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-maps

Estoy leyendo desde una base de datos de oracle las coordenadas para dibujar las formas de google pero no se me muestran en el mapa, mi idea era almacenar  cada coordenada en un array y una vez completado dibujar la forma en el mapa. Este es el codigo que tengo:

Aqui introduzco los datos en un array para despues introducirlas en el mapa, estan ambas partes tanto la que uso para las lineas como la que uso para las formas:

```
<script>  
    if ((valorY != '') && (valorX != '')) {
        var auxvalorX = parseFloat(valorX)
        var auxvalorY = parseFloat(valorY)                           
        if (tipusTall == "2") {
            if (ord == "1") {
                if (TallCarrer.length == 0) {                                     
                    TallCarrer.push(new google.maps.LatLng(auxvalorX, auxvalorY));
                    tallsDeCarrer.push(new google.maps.LatLng(auxvalorX, auxvalorY));      
                    tallsDeCarrerTitol.push(NumExp);
                    tallsDeCarrerExtracte.push('<div id="divInfo"><div id="infoTitol">' + NumExp + '<br />' + Nom + ' (' + Telefon + ')</div><br />' + decInfoAdd + '<br /><br />' +
                        DataInici + ' - ' + DataFi + '<br />' + decCarrer + ', ' + NumCarrer + '<br />' + decEmplacament + '<br />' + decElements + '<br /><br />' + decTipus + ' - ' + decMotiu + ' (' + decMotiuAltres + ')<br />' +
                        '<br />' + decDiesTerminis + '<br />Superficie: ' + Superficie + '<br />Places normals: ' + Normals + ' Places blaves: ' + Blaves + ' Parades bus: ' +
                        ParadesBus + '<br /><br />' +
                        '<a target="_blank" href="http://lhtao/mytao/motores/mtrprc/expedienteDetailAction.do?mode=modify&dboid=' + Dboid + '">Detall</a></div>');
                    comptador++;
                } else {
                    TallCarrerD.push(TallCarrer);
                    TallCarrer.length = 0;                                       
                    TallCarrer.push(new google.maps.LatLng(auxvalorX, auxvalorY));
                }
            } else {                                  
                TallCarrer.push(new google.maps.LatLng(auxvalorX, auxvalorY));
            }
        }
        if (tipusTall == "3") {
            if (ord == "1") {
                if (zonesTallades.length == 0) {                                     
                    zonesTallades.push(new google.maps.LatLng(auxvalorX, auxvalorY));
                    tallsDeCarrer.push(new google.maps.LatLng(auxvalorX, auxvalorY));
                    tallsDeCarrerTitol.push(NumExp);
                    tallsDeCarrerExtracte.push('<div id="divInfo"><div id="infoTitol">' + NumExp + '<br />' + Nom + ' (' + Telefon + ')</div><br />' + decInfoAdd + '<br /><br />' +
                        DataInici + ' - ' + DataFi + '<br />' + decCarrer + ', ' + NumCarrer + '<br />' + decEmplacament + '<br />' + decElements + '<br /><br />' + decTipus + ' - ' + decMotiu + ' (' + decMotiuAltres + ')<br />' +
                        '<br />' + decDiesTerminis + '<br />Superficie: ' + Superficie + '<br />Places normals: ' + Normals + ' Places blaves: ' + Blaves + ' Parades bus: ' +
                        ParadesBus + '<br /><br />' +
                        '<a target="_blank" href="http://lhtao/mytao/motores/mtrprc/expedienteDetailAction.do?mode=modify&dboid=' + Dboid + '">Detall</a></div>');
                    comptador++
                } else {
                    zonesTalladesD.push(zonesTallades);
                    zonesTallades.length = 0;                                 
                    zonesTallades.push(new google.maps.LatLng(auxvalorX, auxvalorY));
                }
            } else {                               
                zonesTallades.push(new google.maps.LatLng(auxvalorX, auxvalorY));
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Aquí es donde se dibujan las formas lo mismo que antes, una es para las líneas y otra para las formas:

```
function zonaTallada() {

           const poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
               paths: zonesTalladesD,
               strokeOpacity: 0.8,
               strokeWeight: 6,
               fillOpacity: 0.35,
               fillColor: "", 
               strokeColor: "" 
           });
           if (tipus == "vorera") {
               color: color["verd"]
           } else if (tipus == "total") {
               color: color["vermell"]
           } else if (tipus == "parcial") {
               color: color["taronja"]
           }
       poly.setMap(map);

       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
           content: tallsDeCarrerExtracte[iterator]
       });
       InfoWindows[iterator] = infowindow;
       google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function () {
           for (i = 0; i < InfoWindows.length; i++) {
               InfoWindows[i].close();
           }
           infowindow.open(map, poly);
       });

       document.getElementById(tallsDeCarrerTitol[iterator]).onclick = function () { canviIcona(poly); openInfoWindow(infowindow, map, poly); };
       document.getElementById(tallsDeCarrerTitol[iterator]).style.fontWeight = 'bold';
           
       }
       function tallCarrer() {

           const poly = new google.maps.Polyline({

               paths: TallCarrerD,
               strokeColor: "",
               strokeOpacity: 0.8,
               strokeWeight: 6,
               fillColor: "",
               fillOpacity: 0.35,
           });
           if (tipus == "vorera") {
               color: color["verd"]
           } else if (tipus == "total") {
               color: color["vermell"]
           } else if (tipus == "parcial") {
               color: color["taronja"]
           }
           poly.setMap(map);

           var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: tallsDeCarrerExtracte[iterator]
           });
           InfoWindows[iterator] = infowindow;

           google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function () {
               for (i = 0; i < InfoWindows.length; i++) {
                   InfoWindows[i].close();
               }
               infowindow.open(map, poly);
           });

           document.getElementById(tallsDeCarrerTitol[iterator]).onclick = function () { canviIcona(poly); openInfoWindow(infowindow, map, poly); };
           document.getElementById(tallsDeCarrerTitol[iterator]).style.fontWeight = 'bold';
         
       }
```

No me aparece ningun error solo que no me muestra las formas, por otro lado la parte en la que añado marcadores si que me funciona correctamente.

Comment: Probablemente el contenido del array no tenga el formato correcto, pero no hay como saberlo. Debes agregar un [MRE] si necesitas mas ayuda, y enfatizo que un ejemplo mínimo NO es copiar una porción de tu código y pegarlo en el sitio. Es crear un ejemplo donde sea posible reproducir tu problema de manera inmediata

Comment: Prueba invertir las coordenadas. Primero Y, luego X. Por eso la clase se llama Latlng